# How much bandwidth does a Skype call use?

Tags: bandwidth, skype-for-web

I'm considering using Skype only for my calls on iPhone. Now that most carriers (in the UK anyway) don't provide unlimited data, and the iPhone can handle Skype with multitasking, are there any metrics on how much data a typical call uses?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a desktop application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Between 30 and 70 kbps, according to this thread on their official forum: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=32510